# What was the intended, more elementary solution to Hatcher $2B.5$? On isomorphisms in homology between a sphere complement and a subsphere

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, spheres

I solved Hatcher's exercise $2B.5$ but I wonder if there is a more elementary approach. Paraphrasing, and removing trivial or vacuous cases, the exercise is this:

> Suppose $n\ge1$ and $0\le k\le n-1$ are integers, $h:S^k\hookrightarrow S^n$ and $h':D^n\hookrightarrow S^n$ are embeddings. Write $D^k\subset D^n$ for the subdisk included in the first $k$ coordinates and $D^{n-k}\subseteq D^n$ for the subdisk included in the last $(n-k)$ coordinates.
>
> If $h'(D^n)\cap h(S^k)=h'(D^k)$ then show that the inclusion $h'(\partial D^{n-k})\hookrightarrow S^n\setminus h(S^k)$ induces an isomorphism on homology.

My solution required the general Schoenflies theorem, see [here](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Eandyp/notes/Schoenflies.pdf) for proofs (I have yet to study this myself).

> Denote $\ell:=h'(\frac{1}{2}(D^k\setminus\partial D^k))$ and $D:=h'(D^n\setminus(D^k\setminus\ell))$.
>
> $D\setminus\ell=h'(D^n\setminus D^k)$ strongly deformation retracts onto $h'(\partial D^{n-k})$ so it suffices to show the inclusion $D\setminus\ell\hookrightarrow S^n\setminus h'(S^k)=(S^n\setminus D')\setminus\ell$ induces an isomorphism on homology. By the long exact sequence of a pair and by excision it suffices to show: $$H_n(S^n\setminus D';D)\cong H_n((S^n\setminus D')\setminus\ell;D\setminus\ell)\cong0$$
>
> This follows from the reduced long exact sequence of a pair and the fact that both $S^n\setminus D'$ and $D$ have trivial reduced homology because, *by the general Schoenflies theorem*, $D'$ is an embedded $k$-disk.

Note that the shortening of $\ell$ to a proper subdisk of $D^k$ so that the intersection $\overline{\ell}\cap h(S^k)$ - the boundary of $D'$ - lies within the 'good space' of $h'(D^n)$ and we can check the manifold/collar neighbourhood condition needed for the general Schoenflies theorem. The shortening of $\ell$ so it lies within $\mathrm{int}\,h'(D^n)$ is also needed for excision to apply.

This is quick and clean and I'm happy with it (well, if you see any errors please let me know!). However I suspect Hatcher had at least one more elementary approach in mind - use of the general Schoenflies theorem *should* be avoidable. How can we do this?

Comment: I could not find this exercise in  Hatcher's AT. Which edition do you use and on which page is the exercise?

Comment: @PaulFrost I mislabelled the exercise unfortunately. It’s $2B.5$. Anyway I use the [version from his website](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT+.pdf) and it’s at the bottom of page $176$ there (book page number, not pdf page number).